# Rails send_file filename utf-8 broken in Internet Explorer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use the following code to send a file in rails:

```
  send_file(file_to_send,
    :x_sendfile  => true,
    :filename    => file_name,
    :type        => file_mime_type,
    :disposition => disposition,
    :stream   => true,
    :buffer_size => 4096)
```

where `file_name` contains a utf-8 filename like `lörem ipsüm.docx`.
In Firefox, Chrome it works fine. In Internet Explorer and even Edge the special German chars (and probably all non default chars) are broken.

The filename on download is `LoÌˆrem ipsuÌˆm.docx`.

After many other things I tried `:filename => URI.encode(file_name)` which leads to a correct filename in IE and Edge, BUT not in Chrome and FF. There I do get the encoded filename `Lo%CC%88rem%20ipsu%CC%88m.docx`.

So anyone has a clue how I can fix this that it works on all browsers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As someone might run into same problem, here is the solution:

```
  send_file(file_to_send,
    :filename => ERB::Util.url_encode(file_name),
    :x_sendfile  => true,
    :type        => file_mime_type,
    :disposition => "#{disposition}; filename*= UTF-8''#{ERB::Util.url_encode(file_name)}", # MSIE & MSEdge requirement to support non Latin filenames
    :stream   => true,
    :buffer_size => 4096)
```